# Sorting for format (Y-m-d H:i:s) is not working in Datatables.net Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datatables

I have a problem with sorting a date column. 
My date is in this format

```
Y-m-d H:i:s
```

And I am getting this output:

```
2012-04-14 23:07:00
2012-01-14 22:40:14
2012-03-09 19:03:20
2012-03-12 16:00:28
2012-05-01 16:09:38
2012-02-11 05:07:08
2012-01-17 15:15:09
2012-03-10 16:02:20
2012-02-09 14:33:19
```

This is my initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        oTable=$('#jphit').dataTable( {
          "sDom": 'T,C<"clear">lfrtip',
             "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
             "oColVis": {
             "buttonText": "Extend table",
            "activate": "mouseover"
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 2 , 4 , 6] }
    ],
            "aoColumns": [
              {
                "mDataProp": null,
                "sClass":"center",
                "sDefaultContent": '<img src="images/plus-icon.png" style="width:27px; height:27px;display: inline;">'
              },
              { "mDataProp": 0 }, //date column
              { "mDataProp": 1 },
              { "mDataProp": 2 },
              { "mDataProp": 3 },
              { "mDataProp": 4 },
              { "mDataProp": 5 },
              { "mDataProp": 6 }
            ],
            "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']], //sort date column
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sScrollY": "500px",
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "history_table.php"
        } );
```

This is my PHP part:

```
$aRow[$iTimestampCol] = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $aRow[$iTimestampCol] );
```

Comment: What is doing the sorting here, exactly? PHP or JavaScript? If you want to sort a formatted date like that you're going to need a binary sort or you can convert the formatted dates to Unix time stamps and sort them as integers. It's not clear to me what is doing the sorting for you here that provided that output.

Comment: PHP line is just converting to date variable and then javascript should be able to sort...but it is not doing it correctly as you can see

Comment: Where is the JavaScript function that's doing the sorting?

Comment: Yes denonth, but it's not immediately clear by your tittle, and thus his perfectly logical question. Also, please add JQuery to your tags

Answer (score 1):

i think you should see this http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting. There are some examples how to do sorting by date.

Comment: You get a +1 for the sake of sorting the site ^_^